# finally is not executed when calling Thread.Abort

Tags: windows, multithreading, mono, abort, threadabortexception

Does anyone know a reason why finally statement wouldn't be executed when calling Thread.Abort? I have thread function like this:

```
void ThreadFunc()
{
    try
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            Debug.Log ("Waiting" + counter);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            ++counter;
        }
        Debug.Log("Success.");
    }
    catch(ThreadAbortException ex)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Cancelled: " + ex);
    }
    catch(System.Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Error: " + ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        Debug.Log("Finally");
    }
}
```

I terminate this thread using Thread.Abort. All I see in output is a bunch of Waiting, but no other lines. My main thread keeps running after calling Thread.Abort (i.e. child thread has enough time to complete). Debug.Log functions are thread safe.

**This happens on Windows. I'm using Mono** (Unity game engine). On Mac it works fine. On iOS I get this behavior, but it seems to depend on device/iOS version or XCode version (I haven't figured out yet). On Windows it happens every time.

BTW: on iOS it crashes if I put another *try {} catch {}* into finally statement.

Is anyone aware why this is happening? It seems to be quite different from what the documentation of Thread.Abort and ThreadAbortException says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mono does not support [Constrained Execution Regions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228973%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and does not fully support catch/finally when Thread.Abort is called.

There is a [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=16808) about this.